# How to set caps lock only for selected signs in css?

Tags: css

I have downloaded a font and I set `font-variant: small-caps;`. Works fine but my numbers are way too big then. And now I want to know if there is any way to set caps lock only for letters, not for the numbers? I know that theoretically numbers don't have caps lock form but in my case they do. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Interesting question. Only with javascript if you are wanting to do it dynamically I guess, or else of course you could just wrap the numerals in `<span>` with a different class.

Comment: Are you looking for `font-variant-numeric: oldstyle-nums;`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-numeric

Comment: @Ryan - Is that a thing?! What support does that have?!

Comment: @mayersdesign: IE10+ http://caniuse.com/#feat=font-feature

Comment: @Ryan - Wow. Always a good day when you learn something :) Can I post that as the answer now?! haha

Comment: @mayersdesign: I don’t know if the asker is actually looking for old-style figures yet, though.

Comment: @Ryan - Yeah but he could probably work with "inherit" at least. Either way. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `text-transform` property.

```css
    p.uppercase, textarea {
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    p.lowercase {
        text-transform: lowercase;
    }
    
    p.capitalize {
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
```

```html
    <p class="uppercase">This is some text. 123</p>
    <p class="lowercase">This is some text.</p>
    <p class="capitalize">This is some text.</p>
    <textarea>This is input text 1234</textarea>
```